# Remove export Formats in devexpress Document Viewer tool

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Hi im currently looking for the solution of the problem im currently using devexpress document Viewer Tool and i notice that when i tried to export the document there are too many formats which is not actually needed so i intent to remove it is there a way to do it? i've tried this code base on my research on the internet

```
ExportOptions options = documentViewer1.PrintingSystem.ExportOptions;

            options.SetOptionsVisibility(new ExportOptionKind[] { ExportOptionKind.RtfExportMode,ExportOptionKind.RtfExportWatermarks,
                ExportOptionKind.RtfPageRange,ExportOptionKind.PdfDocumentSubject, ExportOptionKind.PdfDocumentTitle}, false);
```

but its seems that its not working i want to remove this part please See image 
[image]

did i do something wrong?? i just followed the instruction on the internet but its not really working on my side i want to remove it on run time. THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [`PrintingSystemBase.SetCommandVisibility`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingPrintingSystemBase_SetCommandVisibilitytopic.aspx) method instead of `ExportOptions.SetOptionsVisibility` method:

```
documentViewer1.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(new PrintingSystemCommand[] { PrintingSystemCommand.ExportRtf }, CommandVisibility.None);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for providing this answer one last thing When sending to email i want to add a certain format too?

Comment: @bRaNdOn Use something like this: `PrintingSystemCommand.SendRtf`.